# Generating development container with vsc and copying requirements.txt

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

My directory structure is this:

```
app-dash\
  .devcontainer\
     devcontainer.json
     Dockerfile
  app.py
  requirements.txt
  etc.files
```

I want to have these lines in my Dockerfile

```
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
RUN pip3 --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
  && rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp
```

using this line doesn't work either (with the same error)...

```
COPY ../requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
```

I've also
but in the build process it errors out because it can't find requirements.txt.  If I copy requirements.txt to the .devcontainer directory it'll work.  Of course, I don't want to do that because then if I update one requirements and forget the other it'll be an issue later.  I don't want to only house the requirements.txt in .devcontainer because I want to host this in azure functions which will expect the requirements.txt to be in the root folder.  I also don't want to have to run the build from the command line.

How can I set it up so that when I click to `Open Folder in Container` from vsc that it'll just do it?

Answer (score 3):

The `COPY ../requirements.txt` seems to resolve to `/requirements.txt` which creates the issue.

A quick fix is to change the `"build": {"context": "."}}` property in the `devcontainer.json` file to `..` and change the Dockerfile copy command to `COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/`.  Other `COPY` commands will need to be updated if they're copying anything from the .devcontainer folder, e.g. `COPY .devcontainer/foo foo` as the context becomes the parent folder containing the `.devcontainer` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since it works if you put `requirements.txt` inside `.devcontainer/`, the problem is the path you are using in the COPY instruction. By doing `COPY requirements.txt ...` you instruct the Dockerfile to search for `requirements.txt` in its working directory which is `.devcontainer/`.

By using `COPY ../requirements.txt ...` you'll instruct it to search for `requirements.txt` in `.devcontainer/`'s parent folder, which is `app-dash/` and where `requirements.txt` is actually located.

So just replace the COPY instruction with:

```
    COPY ../requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
```

Comment: nope, same error.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the file? Can you post the logged error so we can see what exactly is happening?

Comment: Yeah, this doesnt work. we need to change the build context to solve this. i know how to do this when building docker on command line or when using a docker-compose file. i dont know how to do it with devcontainer.json in vsc